How does the Ubuntu package manager determine which repository to search for when a user requests to install a package?
How does a package manager, such as APT on Ubuntu, determine the specific repository from which it should retrieve a package when a user requests to install it?

After conducting some research, I've come to understand how the package manager determines which repository to select for installing a package. Let's take the example of the htop package. When we inspect the package details using the apt show command, it provides information structured like this:
Package: htop
Version: 3.0.5-7build2
Priority: optional
Section: utils
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Daniel Lange <DLange@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 342 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34), libncursesw6 (>= 6), libnl-3-200 (>= 3.2.7), libnl-genl-3-200 (>= 3.2.7), libtinfo6 (>= 6)
Suggests: lm-sensors, lsof, strace
Homepage: https://htop.dev/
Task: cloud-image, ubuntu-wsl, server, ubuntu-server-raspi, lubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-mate-core, ubuntu-mate-desktop, ubuntu-budgie-desktop, ubuntu-budgie-desktop-raspi
Download-Size: 128 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
Description: interactive processes viewer
 Htop is an ncursed-based process viewer similar to top, but it
 allows one to scroll the list vertically and horizontally to see
 all processes and their full command lines.
 .
 Tasks related to processes (killing, renicing) can be done without
 entering their PIDs.

By examining the APT-Sources key, we can determine that the package manager will opt for the repository http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main, specified in the /etc/apt/sources.list file to install the package.

This actually doesn't fully answer your question, because the priority is an important part of this. Please see the duplicate linked to above.

Indeed, while prioritization is significant, the initial step involves the package manager's selection of repositories for package installation. Before considering priority, the package manager must determine which repositories to consider.

The command that better shows the relevant information is apt-cache policy (e.g., apt-cache policy htop)
